# Shell Script for CPU load monitoring

Tags: linux, shell, load, cpu-usage

I am looking for a script which does monitor the cpu usage per day. All the scripts that I have come across does kind of real time monitoring and send an email if it meets certain aspects like the load increasing beyond 80%.

Is it possible to monitor and understand the Maximum, minimum and average utilization of a CPU using a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been more than one year to this question and this is how I fixed it at the time. I apologize for the delay in posting as I am not a frequent user.

I have written a script using `vmstat` and wrote the output to the fileload.log on a daily basis. I then took it to internet and there is an excellent load monitoring tool that converts the vmstat log to graphs of CPU, RAM and processor utlis. I have used this free tool to visualize the vmstat graphs.

`vmstat -n 5 > vmstat.log`

Check [VMStax for Visualization of vmstat](http://vmstax.michenux.net/) for uploading the vmstat log to generate the graphs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use below script to monitor server load,

```
#!/bin/bash
r=$(cat /proc/loadavg | awk -F. '{print $1}')
if [ $r -ge 50 ]
then
/bin/mail -s "Warning: High Server Load on: `hostname -i` Load Average: $r"     your@emailid.here
fi
```

save it as, loadmon.sh

add cron:

```
 * * * * * /bin/sh /path/for/loadmon.sh
```

Thanks.

Comment: To get load average in "percent" (that is, integer), you can just use: `awk  '{print $1 * 100}' /proc/loadavg`. If this is not smaller than 100*number of CPUs, the server is under heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't need a script for this task. you can use **mpstat** or **sar**
follow the link for detail description:
http://www.linuxexplorers.com/2012/08/linux-commands-to-check-cpu-and-memory-usage/

Comment: Thans fecub. But both of them do not accomplish what I want. Because I do not have the options -p -r in the RHEL edition of linux I am using. Weird, but can't help.

Is there any other way?

Comment: I am trying to use ksar to see if that helps me. Will post the results back.

Comment: Finally found out that the sar that's in my system is so old that it can give me data only of last september. So whatever I do, I am again at square 1. Now trying to see if vmstat helps me. Thanks